# Call method in TableViewController from within Custom Cell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

There is a button in customCell. When the button is tapped i want to call a method of the tableViewController (the parent view). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a target to your button within your cell

```
newButton.addTarget(self, action: "bttnTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Is bttnTouched a method in the parent view controller?

Comment: Yes you would have to make it and it would take a parameter of AnyObject or UIButton